# To store the images picked by UIImagePicker in iOS

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode4.3, sup

I am working in iOS native development using Objective C. I want to implement camera

functionality in my application. I implemented camera using `UIImagePickerController`. I

am able to take the image and store it in the photo library in **iPAD.Now** I have to store

it  in `BASE 64` format. And I am using **SUP 2.1.3** as my middleware.For that what all

steps I have to do? Please help me to sort out this issue? For that We have to first convert

the image from IPAD to `BASE 64` right? Please suggest something? How can I achieve this?

Comment: "I have to store it in the MBO" -- What is MBO ??

Comment: Sorry, I  am using SUP 2.1.3 as middleware .So there is an MBO(Mobile Business Object) for saving the images.There the data is in BASE 64 format

Comment: Oh, I see. Had no idea about it. Good luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the image data using following code:

```
NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 1.0f);
[Base64 initialize];
NSString *strEncoded = [Base64 encode:data];
```